# Customizable Angular datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

Do you know an Angular datepicker which has input features like:

- Keyboard navigation (e.g. keydown for previous day, keyup for next day) in the input field (so I don't mean in the datepicker popup)
- Autocomplete, e.g. when you fill in 12/12 and tab away, it automatically fills in 12/12/2019
- Keys for specific actions, e.g. T fills in today's date

Or a datepicker which can be easily customized to work like this?

I found that datepickers from libraries like Kendo and Syncfusion try to do too much and are therefore difficult to customize to our needs. They focus on the datepicker popup, while the input field is hard to work with without mouse.

(the old ASP.NET Peterblum components had all this user-friendly functionality which does not seem to be available in modern frameworks, see: http://peterblum.com/DES/DateAndTime.aspx#DateTextBox).

Comment: You can check this: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker and this: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview and as always there is a option to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some date-pickers written in angular here, https://angularscript.com/?s=datetime+picker+. Most of these are customizable as your needs. Thanks